# How can I box fit an image network in a container that has border radius

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how can I box fit an image network within the container with a border radius

```
Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    child: Image.network(
      snapshot.data!,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are using Container with overriding `clipBehavior` and call `decoration`

```dart
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, //default is none
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
  ),
  child: Image.network(
    "",
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    child: Container(
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
        child: Image.network(
        subject['images']['large'],
        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,
    ),)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    child: Image.network(
      snapshot.data!,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: Image.network(
          snapshot.data!,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),),
```

Comment: I have already tried this but still not working

Comment: You can call `clipBehavior` on Container, this will solve the issue